# How to update all array value in document at once

Tags: mongodb

Actually am trying to update an array in my document which have read property is set to false
here what i have done so far.

```
const user = await User.update(
    {
      _id: req.userData.id
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "notifications.$[elem].read": true
      },
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          "elem.read": false
        }
      ], multi : true
    }
  );
```

but am getting an error

```
(node:12572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: No array filter found for identifier 'elem' in path 'notifications.$[elem].read'
```

Comment: could you eventually provide a sample document of your user collection, just with the relevant elements filled. Would be helpful to give you advice. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-elements-match-arrayfilters-criteria) should be defined in `options`.

Try below code:

```
const user = await User.update(
  {
    _id: req.userData.id
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "notifications.$[elem].read": true
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      {
        "elem.read": false
      }
    ], 
    multi : true
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanx It's Working